# How to draw this "front view link top view" animated graphics?

Tags: plotting, animation

## Previous

### Code

```
curve = KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {2, 5}}, "SpaceCurve"];

knot = {knot1, knot2} =
     {curve[u], RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}].curve[u] + {0, 0, 4}};

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{knot1, knot2}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> Left], 
    Graphics3D[{Sphere[knot /. u -> 1.22 Pi, 0.1], Thick, Dashed, Pink, 
        Line[knot /. u -> 1.22 Pi]}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]

Export["01.png", %, Background -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: two knots]

```
Table[
    ParametricPlot3D[curve[u], {u, 0, 2 Pi},
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, SphericalRegion -> True,
    ViewVector -> RotationMatrix[t, {0, 0, 1}].{10, 0, 5}],
    {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}];

Export["02.gif", %,
    "TransparentColor" -> White,
    "TransitionEffect" -> "Background", 
    "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞] // AbsoluteTiming

ListAnimate[%%]
```

[image: knot animation]

### Purpose

I want the 2 graph elements (`knot1` and `knot2`) rotate at the same time, while the left 2 points and  their connection lines <del>do not move</del> keep on the specified side of the view.

---

---

---

## Solution

### Code

```
curve = KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {n = 2, 5}}, "SpaceCurve"];


knotBase = curve[u];
offSet = {0, 0, 4.5};
viewVector = {50, 0, 30};
slant = RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, viewVector}].knotBase;
rotateAroundZ = RotationMatrix[t, {0, 0, 1}];

Default@plot = IdentityMatrix@3;
plot[kI_., vI_.] :=
    Block[{knotCopy = kI.slant + offSet,
           knots = {knotBase, knotCopy},
           viewVector = vI.viewVector}
        ,
        Table[Show[
            ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@knots, {u, 0, 2 Pi}], 
            dotLine = knots /. u -> t/2;
            Graphics3D[{Sphere[dotLine, 0.1],
                        Thick, Dashed, Pink, Line[dotLine]}]
            ,
            PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 7.5}}, 
            Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
            SphericalRegion -> True, 
            ViewVector -> viewVector]
            ,
            {t, 0, 2 n Pi, Pi/90}]]

p1 = plot[];
p2 = plot[rotateAroundZ.RotationMatrix[t, -viewVector],
         rotateAroundZ];

ListAnimate /@ {p1, p2}


pGIF[{p_, name_}] :=
    Export[name <> ".gif", p,
        "TransparentColor" -> White,
        "TransitionEffect" -> "Background", 
        "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞] // AbsoluteTiming

pGIF@# & /@ {{p1, "p1"}, {p2, "p2"}}
```

p1 (stir-like) :
[image: stir-like]

p2 (gear-like) :
[image: gear-like]

Thanks for @HenrikSchumacher's help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have first to rotate the knot, then translate. Instead, you rotate the *whole plot*. Try this:

```
expr =
  {
   {0, 0, 4} + 
    RotationMatrix[
      t, {1, 0, 0}].RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}].curve[u],
   {0, 0, 4} + {0, 4 Cos[u], 4 Sin[u]}
   };
g = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[expr, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> Right, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
    SphericalRegion -> True], {t, 0, -2 Pi, -Pi/20}];
ListAnimate@g
```

Comment: [(a.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R12yt.gif) is OK, but without the outer circle, it shaking again [(b.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVXQf.gif) ?!

Comment: That's because the bounding box varies: The knot has changing radius under rotation. Just prescribe a  fixed `PlotRange` for all frames.